# Strange behaviour on splitting char array and converting the chunks to int

Tags: array

I have this function:

```cpp
void changeColor(char control[16])
{
  char _red[3], _green[3], _blue[3], _brightness[3], _white[3];
  int red, green, blue, brightness, white, offset;

  offset = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    _red[i] = control[i + offset];
  }
  offset = 4;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(green); i++) {
    _green[i] = control[i + offset];
  }
  // strncpy(_green,control+offset,3); // same result
  offset = 7;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(_blue); i++) {
    _blue[i] = control[i + offset];
  }
  offset = 10;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(_white); i++) {
    _white[i] = control[i + offset];
  }
  offset = 13;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(_brightness); i++) {
    _brightness[i] = control[i + offset];
  }

  red = atoi(_red);
  green = atoi(_green);
  //sscanf(_green, "%d", &green); //same result
  blue = atoi(_blue);
  white = atoi(_white);
  brightness = atoi(_brightness);

  Serial.print(" control ");
  Serial.println(control);
  Serial.print(" _red ");
  Serial.println(_red);
  Serial.print(" _green ");
  Serial.println(_green);
  Serial.print(" _blue ");
  Serial.println(_blue);
  Serial.print(" _white ");
  Serial.println(_white);
  Serial.print(" _brightness ");
  Serial.println(_brightness);
  Serial.print(" red ");
  Serial.println(red);
  Serial.print(" green ");
  Serial.println(green);
  Serial.print(" blue ");
  Serial.println(blue);
  Serial.print(" white ");
  Serial.println(white);
  Serial.print(" brightness ");
  Serial.println(brightness);
  //... do something with ints
}
```

And by calling from the setup:

```cpp
 char _control[16]={'6','2','5','5','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','5','0'};
 //6255000000000050

 void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   // ... do something
   while (!Serial) {
     ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
   }
  changeColor(_control);
}
```

I get from console this output:

```
   control 6255000000000050
   _red 255ÿ
   _green 000255ÿ
   _blue 000000255ÿ
   _white 000050000000255ÿ
   _brightness 050000000255ÿ
   red 255
   green 255
   blue 255
   white 29951
   brightness 29951
```

Basically, the char array are filled with more elements than the actual dimension (3), but I don't get error or warnings from the compiler

I also tried with `strncpy`, `strcpy`, `strncat`, and by using the pointer in the for loops

```cpp
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(_green);i++){
  _green[i]=control+i*sizeof(char)+offset*sizeof(char);
} // also without the sizeof()
```

And I got the same result in the console (with nl&cr), any hints?

EDIT:

Added NULL char

```cpp
  ...
  char _red[4], _green[4], _blue[4], _brightness[4], _white[4];
  int red, green, blue, brightness, white, offset;
  _red[4]='\0';
  _green[4]='\0';
  _blue[4]='\0';
  _white[4]='\0';
  _brightness[4]='\0';
  offset=1;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    _red[i]=control[i+ offset];
  }
  // same as above
```

Output:

```
control 6255000000000050
_red 255
_green 100255
_blue 000100255
_white 0000050
_brightness 050
red 255
green 100
blue 0
white 50
brightness 50
```

Comment: Where's the NULL termination of your strings?

Comment: @Majenko, I added the null char(edited the question), but I get messed up output

Comment: In C you start counting from 0, not 1. _red[4] is actually _green[0].

Comment: @Majenko Understood, adding the null character with good index (been coding for too long today!) fixed the issue. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this piece of code you have a strange mix of upper bounds:

```
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    _red[i]=control[i+offset];
  }
  offset=4;
  for(int i=0;i<sizeof(green);i++){
    _green[i]=control[i+offset];
  }
 // strncpy(_green,control+offset,3); // same result
 offset=7;
 for(int i=0;i<sizeof(_blue);i++){
   _blue[i]=control[i+offset];
 }
 offset=10;
 for(int i=0;i<sizeof(_white);i++){
   _white[i]=control[i+offset];
 }
 offset=13;
 for(int i=0;i<sizeof(_brightness);i++){
   _brightness[i]=control[i+offset];
 }
```

The first looks correct at 3.  The second loop has an upper bound of `sizeof(int)` which is 2.  The third loop seems to be `sizeof(char)` which is 1.

Unfortunately non of those values match up with the results you are getting.  What I would try is refactoring whats inside you function to this.

```
int Convert (char* buffer, char const* control, const int& offset, char const* name)
{
    int value = 0;
    for (index = offset; index < offset; ++index)
    {
        buffer[index-offset] = control[index];
    }
    buffer[4] = '\0';
    atoi(buffer);
    Serial.print(name);
    Serial.print(" = ");
    Serial.print(buffer);
    Serial.print("  Value = ");
    Serial.println(value);
    return value;
}
```

And then call it to populate your values:

```
void changeColor(char control[16])
{
    char buffer[4]; // You can reuse this buffer, unless you wanted to have separate ones.
    const int red    = Convert (buffer, control, 1, "red");
    const int green  = Convert (buffer, control, 4, "green");
    const int blue   = Convert (buffer, control, 7, "blue");
    const int white  = Convert (buffer, control, 4, "white");
    const int bright = Convert (buffer, control, 4, "bright");
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(green)` is a typo. This is a much more good looking and working code. Thanks

Comment: re: sizeof(green) I thought so, but just in case it wasn't I thought I'd say.